# .htaccess not working - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've tried to host a CodeIgniter website in Ubuntu server.

All other websites are working fine without any issues (the sever contains WordPress and Laravel applications). But this particular CodeIngniter website is not taking .htaccess file. I've spend a day to figure out the issue, but no luck.

Here is the details.

Website url structure: http://example.com/website_name

**.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Virtual host entry**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
    <Directory "/var/wwww/example.com">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride ALL
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**CodeIgniter config file**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/website_name/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And when I'm trying to access the website the output is as follows,

```
Not Found
The requested URL /website_name/test was not found on this server.
```

But if I add index.php, the the website is working without any issues. I've tried lot methods and it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out the issue by spending an entire day. Here is the solution.

Updated virtual host entry.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/

    # Additional section added to get the htaccess working in sub folder.
    Alias /website_name/ /var/www/example.com/website_name/
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/website_name/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /website_name/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: RewriteBase /website_name/

Comment: Put htaccess file into website_name folder

Comment: I've tried this too (not worked), I'm not sure why this happens since all other websites are working fine in the same server. Did you experienced the same issue?

Comment: move vhost  as first entry

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your .htaccess

`RewriteBase /website_name/`

after your `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Can you check your error_log and access_log of your apache for this domain?

Comment: tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log return nothing related to this website.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling `MultiViews` is probably causing some issues.

Change this in your VHOST

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

to this

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

And also probably add a rewritebase to .htaccess Rewrite

```
RewriteBase /website_name/
```

**Restart apache for config changes**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `.htaccess` like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Or this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the ultimate answer but a good way to test if .htaccess is working at any level.

Create this .htaccess and put in root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Then direct a browser to

```
http://example.com/test.html
```

If you end up on Google then you know .htaccess is working.

A useful way to debug .htaccess is to use its logging function.
Add this to your vhost's configuration:

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

You'll probably need to restart apache to get logging started.